# Closure and variable scope in python 3.x issue causing me confusion

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, closures

I am using Python 3.7.0 and I am doing some experiments in order to comprehend the subtleties of variable scopes but I still don't understand this behaviour.

When I execute this code:

```
def f():
    x=0
    def g():y=x+1;x=y
    return g
f()()
```

I get UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

However when I execute this one:

```
def f():
   x=0
   def g():y=x+1
   return g
f()()
```

It works fine. And even this one:

```
def f():
   x=0
   def g():x=1
   return g
f()()
```

It also works fine. So I am confused. It seems to me that if assigning the value `1` to the nonlocal variable `x` in the `g` function works fine alone and on the other hand if assigning an expression containing `x` to a local variable `y` in the function `g` works also fine then the instructions `y=x+1` and `x=y` should both work. I don't understand what is causing the error. I feel I am missing something fundamental in my understanding of Python's behaviour.

Comment: By "experiences" I meant "experiments", I just edited the question. Sorry, I mixed up English and French, both are not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take an ill-advised crack at this.  In the following code:

```
def f():
    x = 0  # assignment makes this x local to f()

    def g():
        y = x + 1
        x = y  # assignment makes this x local to g()

    return g

f()()
```

The assignment of `x` inside `g()` forces it to be a variable local to `g()`.  So the first line causes the error as you accessing the value of an unassigned local.  I believe this "assignment makes it local" logic doesn't follow the flow of your program -- the function is viewed as whole to make this determination and then the code is looked at line by line.

You can access any variable in scope from a function, but you can only set locals.  Unless you've declared the variable you're assigning as `global` or `nonlocal`:

```
def f():
    x = 0  # assignment makes this x local to f()

    def g():
        nonlocal x

        y = x + 1
        x = y  # x is declared to come from a nonlocal scope

    return g

f()()
```

In your second example, it's not an issue as you're only looking at the value of `x`, not setting it, so it can come from any appropriate scope:

```
def f():
    x = 0  # assignment makes this x local to f()

    def g():
        y = x + 1  # x comes from an outer scope

    return g

f()()
```

Finally, your third example is the same as the first without the unssigned local variable usage error:

```
def f():
    x = 0  # assignment makes this x local to f()

    def g():
        x = 1  # assignment makes this x local to g()

    return g

f()()
```

> It seems to me that if assigning the value 1 to the nonlocal variable
>   x in the g function works fine alone

How did you determine that the reassignment of `x` in `f()` worked fine?

Comment: "How did you determine that the reassignment of x in f() worked fine?"
I am sorry, I thought it is considered nonlocal, my bad.
Your answer makes it clear thank you very much.

Comment: I thought also that python determines the scope considering only the first occurrence of the variable in the function. But you taught me that it reads the function as a whole at first to determine the scopes of each variable then executes line by line, I learned also that, unless declaring a variable as nonloacal, assigning a value to it makes it local even though a previous statement treats it as a nonlocal (I mean reading a value from an unassigned variable makes python look up the nonlocal scope). Please tell me if I am still missing something.